# Logic Natural Derivation in S

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

How do you go about proving this conclusion from the set of premises?

> $$\lbrace A\vee\neg B, \neg A\vee C, \neg C\to B\rbrace\vdash\neg D\vee C$$

I figure that if you assume $\neg C$, you can contradict yourself to end up with $C$. Something like getting $B$ from $\neg C$, and then using $B$ to get $\neg A$, and then $\neg A$ to get $C$ - I just have no idea how to reference these rules.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Using only rules R, ∧I/E, vI/E, →I/E, ⟺I/E, and ¬I/E

Comment: Hint: What is the contrapositive of $\neg C \rightarrow B$?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be →¬? I just don't understand what rules to use to get  from  .

Comment: The contrapositive of $\neg C \rightarrow B$ is $\neg B \rightarrow \neg \neg C$, which is the same as  $\neg B \rightarrow C$. This could be useful since one of your premises is $A \lor \neg B$.

Comment: Another clue could be to try to rewrite $\neg A \lor C$ as an implication.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using only the rules listed: all those rules are valid in intuitionistic propositional logic, yet the turnstile isn't intuitionistically valid; for example, if you assign $A = \bot, B = \bot, D = \top$, and $C$ is some element of a Heyting algebra for which $(\lnot C) = \bot$ but $C \ne \top$, then the hypotheses all evaluate to $\top$ but the conclusion evalutes to $C \ne \top$.  So, long story short, you're going to need to allow some proof rule that is only valid in classical propositional logic.

Comment: @DanielSchepler It is possible if the **variant** of $\neg$ elimination being used is actually Reduction Ad Absurdum.  (As indicated in the comments on the deleted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figure that if you assume $¬C$, you can contradict yourself to end up with 
>   $C$. Something like getting $B$ from $¬C$, and then using $B$ to get $¬A$, and then $¬A$ to get $C$ - I just have no idea how to reference these rules.

A good thought, and very close.

Assuming $\neg C$ you can derive $B$ (from $\neg C\to B$), use that to derive $A$ (from $A\vee\neg B$), and in turn derive $C$ (from $\neg A\vee C$), thereby contradicting the assumption.

This is simple derivation, save that *disjunctive syllogism* is not a fundamental rule of your system.   Its derivation is based on *disjunction elimination* and the *principle of explosion*, which is implemented in your rules through negation-elimination/introduction.

Anyhow, here's how to derive $A$ when given $B$ and $A\vee\neg B$:

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\boxed{\begin{array}{l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}}
{\begin{array}{|l|}&B&\\&A\vee\neg B\\&\fitch{A\hspace{10ex}\mathsf A}{A\hspace{10ex}\mathsf R}\\&\fitch{\neg B\hspace{8.5ex}\mathsf A}{\fitch{\neg A\hspace{6.5ex}\mathsf A}{B\hspace{8ex}\mathsf R\\\neg B\hspace{6.5ex}\mathsf R}\\A\hspace{10ex}\neg\mathsf E}\\&A\hspace{12ex}{\vee}\mathsf E\end{array}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof. Pipe characters | are used to denote lines of hypothesis. Line 13 technically doesn't use any single rule of replacement, but I'm sure the reader can figure out how to make it formal.

1. $A \vee \neg B \quad$ given
2. $\neg A \vee C \quad$ given
3. $\neg C \to B \quad$ given
4. $\neg B \to C \quad$ contrapositive (3)
5. | $A \quad$ assumption
6. | $\neg\neg A \quad$ double negation (5)
7. | $C \quad$ elimination of $\vee$ (2,6)
8. $A\to C$ introduction of $\to$ (5-7)
9. | $\neg A \quad$ assumption
10. | $\neg B \quad$ elimination of $\vee$ (1, 9)
11. | $C \quad$ elimination of $\to$ (4, 10)
12. $\neg A \to C$
13. $(A\vee \neg A) \to C \quad$ combining (8, 12)
14. $\mathbf{T} \to C \quad$ tautology (13)
15. $C \quad$ elimination of $\to$ (14)
16. $\neg D \vee C \quad$ introduction of $\vee$ (15)